# How to access custom attribute added to a product?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, custom-attributes

I have added a custom attribute "flag" to the product. But when I try to access the data using $product->getData('flag');. Its returning null.

I find some way to load custom attribute in the stackexchange by calling raw attribute function.

But when I checked the product object it contain about 43 attributes, includes name, id, thumbnail, type_id etc., so is there a way to configure magento to collect my custom attribute also when it loads other 43 attributes.

Comment: Are you calling the attribute in the product page or in the list page?

Comment: I am calling this attribute from price.phtml. its under catalog/product.

Comment: Have you tried $product->getFlag()?

Comment: Yes its not working.. 'flag' was not part of the 'data' inside product.

Comment: Have you tried flushing cache and rebuilding indexes? Are you sure the product you are using to test has a value set for the new attribute?

Comment: Yes the same code will run for the product page (only configurable product page) there I am able to get the value with getFlag call. 

Also not working in the list page also.

Comment: Do you use Flat Tables?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what it means. ?

Comment: In System->Configuration / Catalog/Catalog/Frontend . Do you have the options 'Use Flat Catalog Category'  and/or 'Use Flat Catalog Product' set to Yes or No?

Comment: Use flag catalog product is set to No

Comment: @ted in what way did you add that custom attribute? Also, on which page are you trying to display that - product page or list of products?